# Not able to use MPMovieAccessLog in iOS 4.3

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to get accesslog from MPMoviePlayerController(In iOS 4.3). But every time it is coming nil. I am playing a video using an URL. Please suggest what i am doing wrong or different from the reference http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMovieAccessLog_Class/Reference/Reference.html

```
-(void) playMovie:(id) object
{
    NSURL *aURL=[NSURL     URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/videos/video1.mp4"];
    NSLog(@"URL %@",aURL);
    theMovie=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init ];
    [theMovie setContentURL:aURL];
   theMovie.scalingMode= MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    [theMovie.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:theMovie.view];
    timer =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self     selector:@selector(getData:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [theMovie play];
}

-(void) getData:(NSTimer*) object
{
    NSLog(@"------------Loggging start-------------");
    MPMovieAccessLog *accessL=[theMovie accessLog];
    NSArray *events = accessL.events;
    for (int i=0; i<[events count]; i++) {
        NSLog(@"-  %@",[events objectAtIndex:i]);
    }
    NSLog(@"------------Loggging end-------------");
}
```

Comment: try using the accesslog after the playback is done / finished / stopped. Still getting nil values?

Comment: every time it was coming nil because MPMovieSourseType was file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation says:

> A movie access log accumulates key
>   metrics about network playback for an
>   associated movie player that is
>   playing streamed content.

Therefore, this functionality available only for streaming content (like HLS video).

Look at [MPMovieSourceType](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/MPMovieSourceType), which specifies types of the movie files.